# I want to share my python app as dmg or package?

Tags: python, macos, package, dmg

I have developed my first .app for mac, written in python and would like to share this .app with some friends.

I have converted the python scripts via py2app. Then I have one .app and compress it to an .dmg file.

I share this .dmg file with the guys and for one, this is working fine. (He has already python installed)

The other people can´t open the .app file, they get error messages. After an intensive search I got it. They have no python installed.

Now my question: How can I include a "one click python installation" in my .dmg file (or as package?!)

Comment: The second case is strange as OS X comes with python...

Answer (score 0):

If you create the `.dmg`, you can setup a background image that tells users to move your application to the /Applications folder. If your application needs no extra setup, this is preferred, or a (Mac OS X created) `.zip` file with it.

The package option is better if some additional setup, or scripts checking for Python dependencies, are required.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. But even if the application is in the correct directory, the users have still no "python" installed, so my script can´t run correctly.

Comment: Well, as you are installing to a Mac, there is a Python installed. If you want to make sure your app has a controlled Python environment, you can embed it with it.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for your answer. My program is working on all Mac BookPro(s) but not on any Mac Mini, but this is another problem.